# How to drag files into Visual Studio running as admin on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, uac, visual-studio-2012

As a web developer I find myself hooking a debugger to the IIS proces all the time. In visual studio 2012 this means that you have to have elevated privileges. In general, this is not a problem, just set VS2012 to run as admin and you're done.

Doing this however makes it impossible to drag files into VS2012 from windows explorer. Being too lazy to use the open file dialog I prefer to just drag files in there.

UAC prevents you from doing this so in Windows 7 we would just turn off UAC and be done with it. In windows 8 this does not work.

There are many guides on the internet on how to disable UAC in Windows 8. Most just say you should move the slider to the button. This does however not actually disable the UAC and after trying this you can still not drag/drop files into Visual Studio 2012.

Other guides speak of disabling UAC by changing a registry setting. This turns off the UAC and allows you to drag/drop files into VS2012, but a side effect of this is that Metro apps can no longer be run. Obviously this kinda sucks too...

Does anyone have any ideas on how to be able to

- Run VS2012 as admin so we can debug iis
- Be able to drag and drop files into VS2012
- Be able to run Metro apps

Thanks in advance

Comment: Solution: Run explorer as admin.  I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: I haven't found a way to do this I'm afraid. But thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Latest version of VSCommands extension for Visual Studio 2012 allows you to run Visual Studio with Medium Integrity Level which will basically allow drag and drop from other windows. You can [read more about it here](http://vscommands.squaredinfinity.com/blog) and download the extension from http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a83505c6-77b3-44a6-b53b-73d77cba84c8

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but the VSCommands IDE Enhancements tab explicitly states: "NOTE: You will not be able to attach to processes run by other users (e.g. IIS)" So I doubt this will work :(

Comment: If it won't work then you can run elevated Windows Explorer from Tools | VSCommands | Elevated Windows Explorer. Elevated Visual Studio will allow you to drop files from Elevated Windows Explorer.

Comment: How about Visual Studio 2015?